A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. HRESULT=0x80131c36. ErrorCode=0x0 in VISUAL STUDIO CODE
while executing the function app
, i console some information to check execution flow ,
but the execution stop at random point(different points at every time i run the function) ,
and the terminal not have any error
but in debug console the fatal error occured
A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. For more details, please see the Microsoft Help and Support web site. HRESULT=0x80131c36. ErrorCode=0x0. The program '[167768] dotnet' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
i tried the try and catch even though ,no error in terminal

Assuming you are using Visua Studio you can break on all Exceptions to see what is going on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022

in visual studio code , i used breakpoint on all exception , eventhough no break points appears

Sounds like a bug in the VS debugger, file it with the product owner.

i started the function app without debugger using  func start command , so the fatal error has not occured
